# How to Update a record if it exists otherwise insert a new record in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql-update, mysql-insert-id

I am trying to write a MySQL query to update a record if it exists otherwise create a new record into 2 different tables. I found some information online but i can't seems to nail it.

This is my current query

```
Set @time_now := NOW();

    if exists(SELECT 1 FROM phone_calls WHERE account_id = 8 AND call_code_id = 5 AND status = 1)
      BEGIN
        UPDATE phone_calls
        SET trigger_on=@time_now,
        isAppointment=1,
        modified_by = 2,
        modified_on = @time_now
        WHERE account_id =8 AND call_code_id = 5 AND status = 1;
       END
    ELSE
      BEGIN
        INSERT INTO phone_calls (mid_id, account_id, call_code_id, trigger_on, created_on, call_subject, status, next_call_id
                                , call_direction, owner_id, workflow_generated, call_notes, total_attempts, isAppointment)
                                VALUES (1, 8, 5, @time_now, @time_now, 'This is a test', 1, 0 , "OUTBOUND", 2, 1, "", 0, 0);
        INSERT INTO inventory_engine_history(phone_call_id, new_phone_call_id, created_by, new_call_owner, action, trigger_on) 
                                                VALUES(1000, LAST_INSERT_ID(), 2, 2, '', @time_now)';
       END
```

I am running into a syntax error

```
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'if exists(SELECT 1 FROM phone_calls WHERE account_id = 8 AND call_code_id = 5 AN' at line 1
```

Can someone please help me with this error?

Note: if multiple records exists I should update all of them but if no record exist them insert only 1 record in each table.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
DECLARE theCount INT;
SELECT COUNT(*) INTO theCount FROM phone_calls WHERE account_id = 8 AND call_code_id = 5 AND status = 1
IF(theCount=0) THEN -- DoLogic;
ELSE -- DoSomeOtherLogic;
END IF
```

Comment: thanks for your answer but I am receiving a syntax error. "#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'DECLARE theCount INT' at line 1 " Also in the section between THEN and ELSE do i write my code with in a BEGIN ... END statment?

Comment: Ok, maybe remove the DECLARE and use SELECT COUNT(*) INTO @theCount...
I am mainly a T-SQL programmer so it is a little different.

Comment: I see, if i change your code I get a different syntax error in the line IF(@count >0) THEN.

Comment: I relized that this type of query only works in a server side in a procedure or a function and not in a client side script like PHP. I will mark your answer correct as you have provided the correct answer. Thanks